# Adding a value to a returned MySQL integer value with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

Can an integer value, for example a product quantity retrieved from a MySQL database with a while loop in php and put in a HTML table, be incremented by a jquery function? Something like if a user clicks a button every time the product quantity would add 1, but done with javascript, not php and sessions. I've tried doing this with jquery `.html()` method but didn't make it. If anybody has any suggestions I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your question seems to be 'is this possible?', if so, yes it is. We'd need to see your code to guide you on exactly how

Comment: Computers are very good at doing arithmetic. How could they not be able to add 1 to a number?

Comment: Really? I thought computers are vitamins. It's not about "adding" a number, it's about adding a given value to a shopping cart script written in php, using jquery, which is not just simple adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onclick jquery event to increment by first fetching the value to be incremented and storing in a variable:

`Var Number = $(this).text();`

Then increment it and set the value using jquery:

```
$(this).text(Number++);
```

Please wrap this using the click event.

```
$('#button'). click(function() {
})
```